# My flutter app, generate multiple register in DB when I press button once

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that contains a form. First, you have to authenticate with your ID, a function checks the date of your last register (if you don't register today, you'll pass. If not you can not log into the form screen). Second, you register your symptoms once a day(restriction of the app), press "ENVIAR(send)" and a POST method storages your data in a DB. It's simple.

In theory, I should see one register per person per day. Now the number of devices with my app installed has increased I can see multiple registers per person in some cases. Curiously the problem happens in just some devices. I cannot detect the problem because with my phone I've never had these kinds of problems (HUAWEI P30 LITE).

I try to debug my code, but it all works perfectly. Could you help or advise me on how to solve this problem, please?

PDT: when I press the button "SEND", the function _submit() is executed, which allows POST the data in the DB. Additionally, to verify the systems works right, I use a developer account with credential "000000000". I had to eliminate many lines, but these are the most important.

Have a nice day.
Thanks

I attach the code:

```
class Tamizaje1Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Tamizaje1PageState createState() => _Tamizaje1PageState();
}

class _Tamizaje1PageState extends State<Tamizaje1Page> {
  final usuariosProvider = new UsuariosProvider();
  final appProvider = new AppProvider();
  final formKey     = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final productoProvider = new ProductosProvider();
  ProductoModel producto = new ProductoModel();
  AppModel app = new AppModel();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
    mostrarPosision();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Center(child: Text('Cuestionario Diario')),
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: (){Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()), (route) => false);},
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _crearBoton1(context),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),  
    );
  }

  Widget _crearBoton1( BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: size.width*0.2,
      height: size.height*0.07,
      focusColor: colorApp,
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 80.0, vertical: 15.0),child: Text('Enviar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 16.0),)),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent,width: 2.0)),
        elevation: 0.0,
        color: colorApp,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: ( _guardando ) ? null : _submit,
      ),
    );
  }


//THIS FUNCTION SENDS THE DATA WHEN PRESS THE BUTTON


  _submit() async {
    
    _noVisibleData();
    if ( !formKey.currentState.validate() ) return;
    formKey.currentState.save();

      if(producto.nroDoc!="000000000" && _currentPosition != null && ((producto.meSiento=='1' && app.diagnostico!='-1') || (producto.meSiento=='0'))){
          bool permtirenvioToDB= await productoProvider.crearProducto(producto); //envia los datos
          if(permtirenvioToDB==true){
                _alertaDeEnvio(context, envio1);
                await enviarGMAIL();
                appProvider.crearApp(app); 
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlertPage()));
          }else{
                contarIntetentosEnvioDB++;
                if(contarIntetentosEnvioDB<5)_soloMensaje(context,"Se ha producido un error al enviar el formulario. Por favor... ¡Inténtalo nuevamente!","assets/alerta0/a0i1.svg",80.0);
                else _soloMensaje(context,"Por favor, ¡Comuníquese con el área de Tecnologías de la Información!","assets/alerta0/a0i3.svg",80.0);
          }

    }else{
              _alertaDeEnvio(context, envio1);
              print('Prueba de desarrollador');
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AlertPage()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to tap on button few times, and check if user is able to run _submit (async) method several times.

Comment: You can also try to add `await Future.delay(Duration(seconds: 3)` at the beginning of the _submit(). This will simulate slow request and allow you to tap few times on the button before logic inside _submit call will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, i debugged many option and realised the errors occurs because i have 3 future functions wich execute when i press the button (inside the butto widget). I created i new page with an additional @averride before Widget build exclusive to execute future functions, and it works good.

```
class _MailDBSendState extends State<MailDBSend> {
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dataBase();
    _sendMail();
  }
.
.
.
.
@override
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
```